# Simple selector matching in cucumber/webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, webrat

I'm having trouble getting a simple CSS selector match working in Cucumber/Webrat.

My step specification begins:

```
Then(/^I should see (.*)$/) do |outcome|
  case outcome
    when /^a login form$/
      puts "!!! Checking #{current_url} for login form"
      expect(response).to have_selector('form.new_user_session')
      # and so on
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
!!! Checking http://www.example.com/login for login form

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find css  "form.new_user_session" but there were no matches
./features/step_definitions/user_logs_in.rb:46:in `/^I should see (.*)$/'
features\user_logs_in.feature:10:in `Then I should see a login form'
```

Presumably the `http://www.example.com` part of what is being checked comes from Webrat - it's not mine. But my /login page contains:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/user_sessions" class="new_user_session" id="new_user_session" method="post"><div style="display:none">
```

I would have *expected* that to match the selector (it certainly matches a `form.new_user_session` selector in the stylesheet). So what am I missing?

Comment: That selector looks OK to me too. It will be hard to get good advice on webrat since the community has moved to capybara, and some tools no longer support webrat.

Comment: Ok, I've moved the project over to capybara - thanks.